# How to have more than one aside section in Friggeri CV

Tags: friggeri-cv

There is a new version of `friggeri-cv.cls` here https://github.com/mlda065/friggeri-letter/blob/master/example-resume.tex .

It works well with TeXLive 2016. However I can add new side sections like I (and the examples) used to.

The current examaple has only one aside https://github.com/mlda065/friggeri-letter/blob/master/example-resume.tex

```
\aside{contact}{
   contact info
}
```

But I can't just add other asides or open sections inside this environment.

How can I add more side sections? Is there a workaround?

In the *old* version, it was as simple as:

```
\begin{aside} 
\section{contact}
contact
\section{languages}
spanish, english
\section{programming}
C++
\end{aside}
```

(see here http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv)

Answer (score 1):

This is the *workaround* I found. It would be better to do without this workaround.

```
\aside{contact}{
John Smith \\
~ \\
\fi
123 Fake St \\
Australia \\
~  \\
02 1234 5678 \\
0412 345 678 \\
~   \\
\href{mailto:example@example.com}{example@example.com} \\
\href{http://www.smith.com}{http://www.smith.com} \\

    \linespread{1}\selectfont
            {\Large\headingfont\color{headercolor} {New Section Title}} \\
    My text
}
```

You still have to use `\ifx \firstPage \undefined
   \xdef\firstPage{}
\else` to have a different aside for the first and second pages.